# What is the correct search.in syntax for Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I've been on the [Microsoft Docs page relating to this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search) for a long time. I keep reading the document and the comments and can't find the correct syntax for my query.

I have a document that has a `PrimaryUnitTypeId` field which is of type `Edm.Int32`. I would like to filter the documents that are returned by that field and would like to use multiple values at once. I am utilizing that .NET Client library as well as the search explorer in the Azure Portal.

My query works if the filter is as follows:
`(PrimaryUnitTypeId eq 1 or PrimaryUnitTypeId eq 2)`

One of the notes on the top of the documentation page though states that this is the sub-optimal way to approach this problem and the `search.in` function should be used instead.

I have tried to switch my filter to `search.in(PrimaryUnitTypeId, '1,2')` or `search.in(PrimaryUnitTypeId, '1,2', ',')` which seems to be the correct syntax according to the documentation, but I keep receiving the following error:

> Invalid expression: No function signature for the function with name
>   'search.in' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures
>   considered are: search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String, Edm.String);
>   search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String).\r\nParameter name: $filter

I have tried utilizing the `2016-09-01` and `2016-09-01-Preview` versions of the API all to no avail.

How do I need to modify the above filter to get Azure Search to recognize and apply the filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `search.in` function currently only supports fields of type `Edm.String`. You can make this scenario work by adding a new string field and populating it with your integer data, or by changing the type of the `PrimaryUnitTypeId` field and recreating/repopulating your index.